# Flutter: App cannot be installed because its integrity can not be verified even after adding UDID of Iphone device on Developer account

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have been running my flutter apps on simulators and recently I had to build an IPA file to test on a physical device. When I try to install on the device it tells me "App cannot be installed because its integrity can not be verified". I did my research and found out that many people who had this issue solved it by adding the UDID of the device to their Apple Developer Accounts. I have added the UDID but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: After adding the udid did you create a new ipa?

Comment: did you update provision profile and then pull again before making ipa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are steps you must follow.

1. Add UDID under devices
2. Update provision profile so that you can add newly added devices in the provision profile.
3. Pull this provision profile in XCode under Accounts section from Preferences menu.
4. Now run OR make ipa file as you want.

*Usually all misses Step 2*

Comment: thanks for the correct information...

Answer (score 0):

The more easy way is to register your device in xCode. Try to run your app on your iPhone, and then xCode will suggest to register your device:

[image]